INA125P does not amplify correctly
I am trying to setup a Wheatstone bridge with just strain gauges (full bridge type 3). I am attaching it to a carbon fibre rod, so the strain is very tiny. When I just measure the output of the bridge the values range from 0.5-0.1mV, therefore I want to amplify the signal. For amplification I use the INA125P instrumental amplifier. I use a gain of RG=10kOhm so the gain should be 10: $$ 4 + \frac{60k\Omega}{10k\Omega} $$
However in combination with the Wheatstone bridge it does not measure any changes when the rod is bent. The output voltage is constant at 2.5V.
To make sure the amplifier circuit is correct I proceed to use a constant voltage supply instead of the Wheatstone bridge. These are my measurements using a power supply as the input signal (VIN) and to power the system (constant 22V):



RG (kOhm)
10
10
10
10
10




Gain (theoretical)
10
10
10
10
10


VIN (V)
1
0,5
0,25
0,1
0,05


Vo predict
10
5
2,5
1
0,5


Vo measured
5,9
3,2
1,7
0,52
0,4



The output voltages are not what I expect and I have tried with a range of RG’s as well. Does anyone know what the problem could be? I use an oscilloscope to measure, and the readings do fluctuate more at lower input voltages, probably due to too much noise.
This is my circuit:



No decoupling supply capacitor don't help ... Wired as near as possible to supply pins.

When you refer to your power supply as "constant 22V" does that mean you're providing +11V to V+ and -11V to V-, with 0V at IAref (pin 5), or do you just have a single 22V supply (with IAref connected to V-)?

I supply 22V to V+ and 0V to V- and I have IAref (pin5) to grnd , so yes 0V

Instrumentation amplifiers not only have an output that has to be kept within supply rails (maybe plus a volt or two) but internal nodes that also have to be kept from saturating. See the right-hand chart below (Vs = +5V), with a single supply, the output voltage cannot go much below 1V and the input common-mode voltage must be greater than a few hundred mV.

In your circuit, both inputs of A2 should be at 0V so the output of A2 would have to go below ground in order to balance, and without a negative rail that's not possible.

I'm not sure of your circuit- it looks like you've shorted out the bottom part of your bridge. Probably the supply is actually connected to ground and pin 3 of the chip.
In any case, the easiest cure is to give it +/-V rather than a unipolar supply.

Hi Spehro, thank you for your response. So you're saying that the input supply V+/- is wrong? I need a dual supply? Because for Vin (pins 6,7) I am just using another power supply to simulate a signal at the moment as the strain gauges were not working.

Ah, where you said "power supply" I mistakenly assumed it was there to supply power rather than signal.

INA125 is not a "single supply" amplifier - it needs dual supplies. Refer to the "Input Common-Mode Range" section of the datasheet on page 11.

If you calculate (or measure) the voltage levels at Vin+ and Vin- and push those into the formula you'll find that you're asking the internal A2 opamp in the INA125 to try to produce an output that's lower than the V- supply rail you're giving it.
As a result, the final output (from A1) is not what you'd want to see.

Thank you! So it would be better to use a dual supply instead? As I cannot guarantee the voltages of Vin to be above 1V which is needed for single supply operation I believe.
